# disable jFrame window without hiding it

Tags: jframe

I launch a jFrame (Frame B) window on a click event of a button that belongs to another jFrame (Frame A) window.
I have used setEnabled(false) in Frame A and added a windowClosed event listener for Frame B where i use setEnabled(true) to enable the Frame A again.
I have observed that I need to use setVisible(true) to show the Frame A window again after Frame B is closed, else Frame A gets hidden.
Due to this hiding/showing events, there is some kind of flickering in Frame A after Frame B is closed.
Is there any other method that I can use to disable (no input fields or buttons should be clickable) Frame A while Frame B is open?

Comment: [How to make dialogs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) - what you seem to be after is a modal dialog

Comment: i wanted to avoid modal dialog. guess no other option but to use it.

Comment: It's what it's designed for 

Comment: @MadProgrammer you are right. thanks.